# supporting unicode in rust lexer

Tags: performance, rust, unicode, lexical-analysis

I am working on a lexer in rust.
It has been through many different iterations, going from iterating over a `Vec<char>` to `std::str::Chars` to `std::str::CharIndices`,
from pushing `char`s onto a String to taking a slice of a `&str`.
i'm trying to speed up my implementations, so today i decided to ditch the `Chars` and instead have been experimenting with a `&[u8]` based approach.
The problem is, not all characters are ascii, and this makes indexing the `&[u8]` quite hard.
I've figured out a solution with `u8::leading_ones` but this still doesn't solve the problem of implementing `take_while`.
Right now it only works with ascii `char`s/`u8`s, but doesn't support unicode. The reason is, to check a predicate against a unicode `char`, i need to:

1. get the character width using the leading ones of the first character
2. take a slice of the `&str`
3. ok, now what?
   The `&str` slice mentioned in step 2 can be implemented in `take_while` using `&self.string[s..self.pos]` however, this is still a `&str` and not a `char`.
   I *could* just get the character using `.chars().next()` however this seems too hacky and weird to me.
   The "WET" alternative would be to clone the code from `take_while` for every time i want to parse a token, and use a hacky approach when i actually want to check if a unicode character matches a predicate (e.g: parsing an identifier)
   Any ideas?

```rust
struct Cursor<'a> {
    bytes: &'a [u8],
    string: &'a str,
    pos: usize
}

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    pub fn new(string: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self {
            bytes: string.as_bytes(),
            string,
            pos: 0
        }
    }

    pub fn next_char(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        let start = self.pos;
        if start >= self.string.len() {
            return None;
        }
        self.pos += self.bytes[start].leading_ones() as usize;
        if self.pos == start {
            self.pos += 1;
        }
        Some(&self.string[start..self.pos])
    }

    pub fn take(&mut self, amount: usize) -> Option<&'a str> {
        let start = self.pos;
        for _ in 0..amount {
            let s = self.pos;
            if self.pos >= self.string.len() {
                return None;
            }
            self.pos += self.bytes[self.pos].leading_ones() as usize;
            if self.pos == s {
                self.pos += 1;
            }
        }
        Some(&self.string[start..self.pos])
    }

    pub fn take_while<F: FnMut(u8) -> bool>(&mut self, mut pred: F) -> &'a str {
        let start = self.pos;
        loop {
            if self.pos >= self.string.len() - 1 {
                self.pos += 1;
                break
            }
            let s = self.pos;
            self.pos += self.bytes[self.pos].leading_ones() as usize;
            if self.pos == s {
                self.pos += 1;
                if !pred(self.bytes[self.pos]) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        &self.string[start..self.pos]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cursor: Cursor<'_> = Cursor::new("123NowTheIntegerLiteralIsOver");
    println!("{}", cursor.take_while(|x| x.is_ascii_digit()));
}
```

(and yes, `Cursor` will `impl Iterator` in future, only in this case will yield `&str` or a possible `Token` type rather than `char`)

Comment: Note: Chars method is faster in release mode, but slice method is faster in debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Cursor<'a> {
    bytes: &'a [u8],
    string: &'a str,
    pos: usize
}
```

Having both `bytes` and `string` is redundant because they are both the same thing. In terms of memory layout `&str` and `&[u8]` are exactly the same. I think you do this so that you can slice the string:

```
&self.string[start..self.pos]
```

Both this doesn't do what you probably want. In particular, slicing a `str` does a runtime check for the validity of the slice indexes which rather defeats the purpose of operating at the u8 level. You probably want:

```
unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.bytes[start..self.pos]) }
```

This is unsafe because it is up to you to ensure the correctness of the slice indexes.

```
let s = self.pos;
self.pos += self.bytes[self.pos].leading_ones() as usize;
if self.pos == s {
    self.pos += 1;
}
```

I'd do:

```
self.pos += self.bytes[self.pos].leading_ones().max(1) as usize;
```

In general you can create a reusable function for moving forward in the stream:

```
fn move_forward(&mut self) -> bool {
    if self.pos >= self.string.len() {
        return false;
    }
    self.pos += self.bytes[self.pos].leading_ones().max(1) as usize;
    true
}
```

Then you can use it to get rid of most the repetition in your functions: